# Need help in Javascript with do while

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I need a "do while loop" until one of three specific words is written in a prompt box.

for example

```
do 
    var test = prompt("");
while test =! word1 word2 word3
```

when one of the three words is written, the script should go on.
im trying for over 2 hours but i still dont solve the problem.

please help.

Comment: ive tried for more then 2 hours but i still cant solve the problem

Comment: Your comparison operator is backwards, `!=` not `=!`, and you have to test against each word, `test != word1 && test !=word2 && test != word3`

Comment: I would suggest you stop trying, and get a book or a tutorial site that targets beginners before proceeding further. Proper understanding of conditionals is required to achieve pretty much everything in any language.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
while (test != word1 && test != word2 && test != word3) {
    var test = prompt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
while (test != word1 && test != word2 && test != word3)
```